# Destructor of a global static variable in a shared library is not called on dlclose

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, dlopen

In a main program, I `dlopen` and `dlclose` (`LoadLibrary` and `FreeLibrary` respectively) a shared library. The shared library contains a static variable that is instantiated upon `dlopen`, and destroyed upon `dlclose`. This behavior is consistent on MSVC 2008 and 2013, GCC 3.4.6, and  Sunstudio 12.1.
With GCC 4.9.1 and GCC 5.2.1 however, the destructor was no longer called on `dlclose`. Instead, it was called before program exit.

The particularity of the static variable's class, is that in the constructor, there is a call to a templated function *get* (of global scope) that returns a local **static** variable.

I was able to reproduce this behavior with the following one cpp file linked into a shared library:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> // In my actual code, i is of type T, however, this has no effect
int get()
{
   static int i = 0;
   return i;
}

class Dictionary {
public:
   Dictionary()
   {
      std::cout << "Calling Constructor" << std::endl;
      get<int>();
   }
   ~Dictionary(){
      std::cout << "Calling Destructor" << std::endl;
   }

private:
   Dictionary(const Dictionary&);
   Dictionary& operator=(const Dictionary&);
};
static Dictionary d;
```

I investigated the tweaks that can be made in order to have the destructor called on dlclose, and concluded the following:

- If the function *get* was not templated
- else if the variable i in the function *get* was not static
- else if the function *get* is made static

The main program's code is the following:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void* LoadLib(std::string name)
{
      void* libInstance;
      name = "lib" + name + ".so";
      libInstance = dlopen(name.c_str(), RTLD_NOW);
      if ( ! libInstance ) std::cout << "Loading of dictionary library failed. Reason: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
      return libInstance;
}

bool UnloadLib(void* libInstance)
{
     int ret = dlclose(libInstance);
     if (ret == -1)
     {
        std::cout << "Unloading of dictionary library failed. Reason: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
        return false;
     }
     return true;
}

int main()
{
   void* instance = LoadLib("dll");
   assert(instance != 0);

   assert(UnloadLib(instance));
   std::cout << "DLL unloaded" << std::endl;
}
```

I built the binaries with the following commands:

```
g++ -m64 -g -std=c++11 -shared -fPIC dll.cpp -o libdll.so
g++ -m64 -g -std=c++11 -ldl main.cpp -o main.out
```

The output I get when the destructor is called before program exit is the following:

```
Calling Constructor
DLL unloaded
Calling Destructor
```

The output I get when the destructor is called on dlclose is the following:

```
Calling Constructor
Calling Destructor
DLL unloaded
```

Questions:

- If the change of behavior between the versions of GCC is not a bug, can you please explain why is the destructor not called on dlclose?
- Can you please explain for each tweak: Why is the destructor called on dlclose in this case?

Comment: Sounds like a bug report you should make against GCC

Comment: static variables are now thread-safe (they have to be due to C++ standard changes introduced in C++11).  Possibly this makes a difference.  Visual Studio 2013 did not have this implemented, while 2015 does.  Maybe you should test with 2015.  Only gcc 4.x and above implemented this, so that's why you should see if the static variable threading requirement is playing a role.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no guarantee that unloading (destructors are invoked) happens on dlclose. On [musl](http://wiki.musl-libc.org/wiki/Functional_differences_from_glibc#Unloading_libraries) (as opposed to glibc), constructors only run the first time a library is run, and destructors only run on exit. For portable code, dlclose cannot be assumed to unload the symbols immediately.

The unload behavior depends on glibc's symbol binding when doing dynamic linking, and is independent of GCC.

The static variable `get::i` has a `STB_GNU_UNIQUE` binding. For static variables in inline functions, the uniqueness of the object is assured by the ELF linker. However, for dynamic loading, the dynamic linker assures uniqueness by marking the symbol `STB_GNU_UNIQUE`. Hence, another attempt to dlopen the same shared library by some other code will lookup the symbol and find that it is unique and return the existent one from the unique symbols table. A symbol with unique binding cannot be unloaded.

Unique binding can be disabled with `-fno-gnu-unique` if not needed.

**References**

[Bug that I raised to GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71971)

[STB_GNU_UNIQUE](https://www.redhat.com/archives/posix-c++-wg/2009-August/msg00002.html)