# What is the difference between __cxa_atexit() and atexit()

Tags: c++, atexit

In the [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html) I found the `-fuse-cxa-atexit` option and it says the following:

> This option is required for fully standards-compliant handling of static destructors

So what is the difference between the two? In the docs for `__cxa_atexit` I found the following:

> The __cxa_atexit() function is used to implement atexit()

I'm implementing statics in functions (don't ask why) and I was wondering which of the 2 to use for calling the destructor.

And I guess I only have `atexit()` for MSVC? Is that a problem?

Can I just use `atexit()` everywhere and be sure that it would behave just like real static objects in functions would?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`__cxa_atexit()` is defined in the Itanium C++ ABI. The document explained the [motivation behind this function](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#dso-dtor-motivation):

> The C++ Standard requires that destructors be called for global objects when a program exits in the opposite order of construction. Most implementations have handled this by calling the C library `atexit` routine to register the destructors. This is problematic because the 1999 C Standard only requires that the implementation support 32 registered functions, although most implementations support many more. More important, **it does not deal at all with the ability in most implementations to remove [Dynamic Shared Objects] from a running program image by calling `dlclose` prior to program termination.**
>
> The API specified below is intended to provide standard-conforming treatment during normal program exit, which includes executing `atexit`-registered functions in the correct sequence relative to constructor-registered destructors, and reasonable treatment during early DSO unload (e.g. `dlclose`).

So:

- `__cxa_atexit()` is not limited to 32 functions.
- `__cxa_atexit()` will call the destructor of the static of a dynamic library when this dynamic library is unloaded before the program exits.

You *should* enable `-fuse-cxa-atexit` if you are writing a library, and your libc has this function (e.g. glibc, musl). In fact, the gcc that comes with your distro might have this flag enabled automatically already (there will be a linker error if you enable the flag and the libc doesn't support it).

Note that [users should not call `__cxa_atexit` directly](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#dso-dtor-runtime-api): it takes arguments which only the compiler/linker is supposed to know ([the `__dso_handle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308720/where-is-dso-handle-defined)).

> … No user interface to `__cxa_atexit` is supported, so the user is not able to register an `atexit` function with a parameter or a home DSO.

---

MSVC apparently [does not use `atexit()`-like functions](http://wiki.osdev.org/C%2B%2B#Global_objects) to run the global destructors. And according to [Destructor of a global static variable in a shared library is not called on dlclose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510621/destructor-of-a-global-static-variable-in-a-shared-library-is-not-called-on-dlcl) MSVC already run destructors on `dlclose()`.

Comment: soooooo for emulating the lifetime of local statics - simply using ```atexit()``` will not be 100% the same as what the compiler generates?

Comment: @onqtam Right. Instead of `atexit`, you could create a local struct which the destructor calls that handler. `static struct Foo { ~Foo() { handle(foo); } } foo_dtor;`

Comment: There is a typo in the first line: Italium C++ ABI. should be  Ita*n*ium C++ ABI. Unfortunately the stackoverflow won't allow me to edit the post changing less than 6 chars.

Comment: @morty Thanks, fixed